# Semi direct Product question?

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

**SETUP:**  Let $G$ be a group such that $G= N \times_\varphi H$ semi-direct product of $H$ and $N$ with respect to the action $\varphi$. Denote: $$p(G):= \max\{ p \in \mathbb{N}^*\: | \: \mathbb{R}^p \cong K < G \}$$

I know that if $ \varphi = id $ then $ p(G) = p(N)+p(H) $ and that there are some conditions on $\varphi$ such that $p(N \times_\varphi H) = p(N \times H)$.

My question is there, in general, a formula to calculate directly $p(N \times_\varphi H)$ in the function of $p(N)$, $p(H)$, and a constant related to $\varphi$?

Comment: What is a semi-product? Do you mean a semidirect product?

Comment: It's called a "semidirect product", not a semi product.

Comment: My bad, yes it is the semi-direct product

Comment: I do not understand the question since all these $R^p$'s are pairwise isomorphic (if $p>0$). Are you working with topological groups by any chance?

Comment: @MoisheKohan, $p(G$) is the maximal integer $p$ such that $\mathbb{R}^p$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Yes, this is totally clear. My point is that $p(G)$ (the way you defined it) can only take two values: $0$ and $\infty$. The reason is that the groups ${\mathbb R}^p$ are pairwise isomorphic as long as $p\in {\mathbb N}\cup \{\infty\}, p\ne 0$, and ${\mathbb R}^\infty$ is understood as a countably infinite direct sum of copies of the group $\mathbb R$. Thus, $p(G)=p(N)+p(H)$,  regardless of $\phi$. Here, of course, one uses the convention that $\infty+\infty=\infty$, $0+\infty=\infty$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan; No, $p(G)$ is finite and we have $p(G) \leq p(G/K)$, where $K$ is the maximal compact subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Then you are actually working in the category of topological groups and your question should be edited appropriately. Voting to close for now due to lack of clarity.

Comment: @MoisheKohan clarity of what?? my question is clear !!!

Comment: No: I asked you if you are working with topological groups. You did not answer. Then you have mentioned compact subgroups of $G$ even though this makes no sense without a fixed topology.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, I was reading about the semi-direct product and I came up with this question .... what if we have a group $G$ of this form can I figure out this invariant ''$p(G)$''... I found later that if I have a direct product then it is trivial $p(G)=p(N)+p(H)$ later on I found that there are some conditions about $\varphi$ that gives me the right to say that $N \times H \cong N \times_\varphi H$. Now what about other cases !?

Comment: What is $K$ in $p(G)$'s definition?

Comment: The question is unclear first for the reason mentioned by @MoisheKohan, but more severely because of the "some conditions" and "is there a formula" weasel wording. What formula can you expect better than the definition? (NB. There is a semidirect product $G = \mathbb R \rtimes \mathbb R$ with $p(G) = 1$.)